# Macro Command for every pgfplot graph to be Very thick

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to figure out a macro so that when I am creating plots I do not have to continue to add the option of ''very thick'' for any plot I create.  For example,

```
\addplot[very thick, domain=-2:2,samples=1000]{x^2};
```

I tried this in my preamble, but it did not work

```
\pgfplotsset{every plot/.append style={very thick}}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{multicol,array,fancyhdr,fullpage,setspace,parskip,adjustbox,float}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

%TIKZLIBRARY PACKAGES
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\tikzset{font=\footnotesize} 
\newcommand{\bb}{\textbf}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{3}

%PGF GLOBAL COMMANDS
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\small, yshift=0.5ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\small, xshift=0.5ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every major tick/.append style={thick, major tick length=10pt, black}}
\pgfplotsset{grid style={line width=.75pt, draw=gray!50}}

\pgfplotsset{every plot/.append style={very thick}} %HERE IS MY CODE


% HEADER AND FOOTER
\newcommand\course{AP Calculus AB}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight 35pt
\lhead{}
\chead{\textbf{Topic 8.11 Volume with Washer Method \\ Revolving Around the x- or y axis}}
\rhead{\course \\ \today}
\lfoot{Mr. Bennett}
\cfoot{Flint Hill Upper School}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}
\headsep 1.5em


\begin{document}

    
\subsection*{Example 1}

Find the volume of the solid formed by the region bounded by the graphs of \(y=x^2\) and \(y=\sqrt{x}\) about the \(y\)-axis. 
  
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis,
            axis lines=middle,
            inner axis line style={-Triangle},
        axis line style = very thick,
            ymin=-.5,
            ymax=1.5,
            xmin=-.25,
            xmax=2,
        every major tick/.append style={very thick, major tick length=10pt, black},
         ]

  \addplot [very thick,domain=0:1, samples=1000, name path=f, thick, color=red!50]
        {x^2};
    \addplot [domain=0:1, samples=100, name path=g, very thick, color=blue!50]
        {sqrt(x)};
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you want [`every axis plot`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-styleoptions#pgfp./pgfplots/every:axis:plot) instead of `every plot`.

Comment: stink pots.  I was so close!!! Thank you